# Rackspace - if I delete a server will I lose the backups?

Tags: backup, image, rackspace

I've just started using Rackspace and was disappointed to find I have to install the whole LAMP stack myself. This isn't a big deal if I only have to do it once.

I've set up a test server to try things out, which I will delete in the future.

From the RS knowledge base I can see that I can create new server instances from any backup.

But I was unable to find out if deleting an instance also deletes the backups.

This is important because I want to ensure the work done in configuring the test server isn't lost.

Any advice greatly appreciated, tks.

Comment: Sounds like a question which would have been great to ask the Rackspace support about?

Comment: You're talking about Rackspace Cloud Servers right? We have both managed dedicated servers and a managed Rackspace private cloud (i.e. VMware virtual servers), and Rackspace installs and configures the LAMP stack for us. Also, in those cases backups are stored off-server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default your backups are on the server it self so when you delete the server backups will be deleted, but an other option is to do your backups on cloud files, you'll have to activate that option by raising a ticket in the support section.

There are extra charges to store backups on cloud files but they are very minimal.